# How can I compress this list of data into one field?

Tags: php, string, excel, csv

I have a database that lists the trim and engines to each make and model per model year, and it lists the Trim & Engine to the Make & Model in each line. I want to compress and output this data into a CSV spreadsheet so each Make & Model is on one row, with the Trim and Engine data compressed into one column each.

The database is currently in SQL, so I can either do it server side (example, PHP and then output into a CSV format) or I can output the data into a CSV format and manipulate the data on my computer (example, using Excel if this would even be possible with that, or something else). There are around 50,000 lines that I estimate will be compressed down to around 8,000.

**I want to take this:**

```
Vehicle:                    Trim:           Engine: Year:

Chevrolet Impala            LS              2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Impala            LS              3.6L    2015    
Chevrolet Impala            LT              2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Impala            LT              3.6L    2015    
Chevrolet Impala            LTZ             2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Impala            LTZ             3.6L    2015    
Chevrolet Malibu            LS              2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Malibu            LT              2.0L    2015    
Chevrolet Malibu            LT              2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Malibu            LTZ             2.0L    2015    
Chevrolet Malibu            LTZ             2.5L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    High Country    5.3L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    High Country    6.2L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    LT              4.3L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    LT              5.3L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    LTZ             5.3L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    LTZ             6.2L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    WT              4.3L    2015    
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    WT              5.3L    2015
```

**And compress it into unique lines:**

```
Unique Vehicle:             Unique Trims:               Unique Engines:     Year:
Chevrolet Impala            LS, LT, LTZ                 2.5L, 3.6L          2015
Chevrolet Malibu            LS, LT, LTZ                 2.0L, 2.5L          2015
Chevrolet Silverado 1500    High Country, LT, LTZ, WT   4.3L, 5.3L, 6.2L    2015
```

Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Assuming MySQL (you don't specify), then the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function may help

Comment: Or just export the whole thing into a regular csv file and then concat it in Excel.

Comment: Yes, the database is hosted in a MySQL format on an online server. I need to output the final result into a CSV file for local editing. The GROUP_CONCAT() function may help, but I would have no idea how to differentiate the VEHICLE lines automatically, so it knows when it's a different vehicle (Impala, Malibu, Silverado 1500, etc).

Comment: Haven't you ever used a GROUP BY clause in SQL before?

Comment: @MarkBaker, I'm not a programmer that knows how to do a lot of things.. I've only dabbled in various languages :)

Comment: `SELECT vehicle, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trim) AS unique_trims, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT engine) AS unique_engines, year FROM vehicles_table GROUP BY vehicle, year ORDER BY vehicle, year`

Comment: The answer is to [read about it](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) and try it for yourself; but part of the magic is in that DISTINCT

Comment: It is easy to write a code in php to make your new text template. Put all of the texts in a 2D array and use a "for" loop to make the new compact array and finally convert the new array to the new text file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using MySQL (you don't specify), then you can use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT vehicle,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trim ORDER BY trim) AS unique_trims,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT engine ORDER BY engine) AS unique_engines,
       year 
  FROM vehicles 
 GROUP BY vehicle,
          year 
 ORDER BY vehicle, 
          year
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b044/3)